# Node.js app doesn't load when location path is not /

Tags: nginx, node.js

For some reason, my Node.js app running on `127.0.0.1:8081` requires `/`.

If I start with this, **BOTH `/` and `/projectb` are able to load the page**.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /projectb {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

When I change it to this, `/projectb` is no longer able to fully load the page. When I look at the network tab, some *(but not all)* requests fail, for example some images, .js, some wrong endpoints.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        location /somethingelse {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /projectb {  # I'd expect this to still work.
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

To summarize, it works when I hit the port directly `123.456.78.910:8081`, and when I have BOTH `/` and `/projectb` proxy to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`, but not when I proxy to `/projectb` by itself.

Why might this be the case?

Comment: What requests failed?

Answer (score 0):

From [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) on `proxy_pass`:

> If the `proxy_pass` directive is specified with a URI, then when a
> request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
> matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
> }
> ```
>
> If `proxy_pass` is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to
> the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original
> request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed
> when processing the changed URI:
>
> ```
> location /some/path/ {
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```

In your 2 examples, the latter one provides a URI (terminating `/` in the URL), which makes the URI being normalised, this would make relative links in js/css files to break. Remove the `/`:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        location /somethingelse {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /projectb {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```